# add_submenu_page to a php file not a function

Tags: wordpress

I am using the below code to add a menu and add a sub menu.

```
function register_gapi_menu_page(){

   add_menu_page( 'Posts with analytic', 'Posts with analytic', 'manage_options', 'analyticapi/gapi.php', '', '' ); 
   add_submenu_page( 'analyticapi/gapi.php', 'Test Analytic', 'Tests', 'manage_options', 'analyticapi/test.php', '' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_gapi_menu_page' );
```

It works fine when I work in localhost. I get two link to handle each menu page. which work PERFECTLY the way I want.

```
http://wordpress.local/wp-admin/admin.php?page=analyticapi/gapi.php

http://wordpress.local/wp-admin/admin.php?page=analyticapi/test.php
```

.

But when i upload it to my server. The Submenu page link become.

```
http://www.xxxxxx.org/wp-admin/analyticapi/test.php
```

Which give me 500 Internal Server Error

And if I change the submenu code into  ( prefixing admin.php?page= )

```
add_submenu_page( 'analyticapi/gapi.php', 'Test Analytic', 'Tests', 'manage_options', 'admin.php?page=analyticapi/test.php', '' );
```

When I visit the link. It says "I DONT HAVE ENOUGH PERMISSION TO VISIT"

How i can fix this?  I want to use separate php file for each menu page.

Comment: looks like a permalinks issue? have you tried with default permalinks on instead of 'nice' ones?

Comment: I am having the same permalinks structure on both local and server :(

Comment: you probably haven't setup your `.htaccess` file (correctly) on the server - verify if it's there at all or of you have maybe a separate one setup in your root folder... by the way, when prefixing `admin.php?page=` you probably get the error because `admin.php` file might not be existing...